# seg fault due to same file name / class names present in different so's

Tags: c++, linux, object, shared

I will try my best to explain.

BaseModule.so has

- core.h with class named core. core.cpp has the implementation
- access1.cpp derived from core
- access2.cpp derived from core

Module1.so has

- Mod1.cpp / h has declarations and implementations for Mod1 class
- ModHelper.cpp gives values to the Mod1 class
- core.h core.cpp has a class named core that helps ModHelper calculate values (function signatures are very similar to the core class in the Base module with some changes in implementation)

Module2.so

- Mod2.cpp / h has declarations and implementations for Mod2 class
- ModCalculator.cpp / h helps calculate values for Mod2 class
- ModCalculator uses objects of access1 access2 from the BaseModule

***Segment fault*** when all the three modules are loaded

Segment fault at Module two, I find that access1 class in Module Two is using core.cpp functions from Mod1.so instead of using the ones from BaseModule

Shouldn't it be using the core.cpp functions from BaseModule as they are different so's ?

I can only modify Module one
How to resolve this, how to prevent such things from happening in future ..

Compiler gcc in Linux 
We are adding Modules … and not to touch the BaseMod functions.

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible code.

Comment: `function signatures are very similar to the core class in the Base module with some changes in implementation` then you should use namespaces so that the names do not conflict, or don't use the same names for the classes.

Comment: Wondering how does the name conflict even though they are classes in totally different so's ? and moreover, shouldn't the derived attribute call its base class methods instead of calling methods of a class with similar name? Its puzzling me all the more.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution for the above issue.

The issue was .. 
The makefile of the Module1.so had a reference to the BaseModule library, and hence, when the next so (Module2) was trying to access the BaseModule references, the functions in the core (core.cpp) were being overridden with the functions of the core.cpp in the Module1.so

Modifying the makefile (Removing the library reference to the BaseModule) resolved my issue.